# Acquiring Lock with retry mechanism with low Latency

Tags: mysql, database, google-cloud-firestore, database-design

I am working on a data processing product and there are concurrent users that ask for the data to work on in a particular state.

```
For example, users can ask to assign me a data-id where status is `Not_Assigned` or `In_Review`.
```

As there could be concurrent requests and everyone should get a unique Id, I thought of using database locking, but in this case, I have a problem of retrial **[In case of a thread is not able to acquire lock transaction will fail]** and control goes back to application and application will retry to fetch a new Id so End-user will face higher latency. Can someone guide me on a better approach to solve this or guide me on how you solved a similar problem?

For reference, my sample data will look like below.

```
Data_id | Status       | UserId
   1    | Not_Assigned | NULL
   2    | REVIEW       | 1
   3    | DONE         | 2
   4    | Not_Assigned | NULL
   5    | Not_Assigned | NULL
```

So in case two users come and ask for data with `Not_Assigned` state they should get unique id's from `(1,4,5)` that I can handle with adding a lock on DB.

Comment: Do they just get one not assigned id? More than one?  Are they assigned to the one(s) they get, or does something client-side have to happen first?

Comment: Explain what you mean by "retrial and control goes back to the application"; what you are concerned about is not clear.

Comment: My application responsibility is to assign an id to that user which is not assigned to anyone. There are a few more business scenarios involved like giving a user id that is already assigned to him but not moved to the done state this scenario can be handled once the original problem is handled.

Comment: For robustness you should retry after a deadlock or a lock timeout, but that really isn't likely to be common enough to worry about.  Just do a simple update with a limit of 1.

Comment: I also thought about as a dining philosopher perspective but with a max retrial policy

Answer (score 1):

If you use an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column for assigning new ids, there is never any concurrency problems.

If you use some other mechanism, be sure to use InnoDB, `START TRANSACTION`, `COMMIT` and, when necessary, `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`.

Always check for errors after any queries.  Errors (eg, concurrency issues) may occur while inside a transaction.  Plan on rerunning the entire transaction.

Comment: Here Id's are already there it's about choosing an Id from table

Comment: How do you choose an existing id from the table?

Comment: @Key_coder - `SELECT data_id FROM tbl WHERE status = 'REVIEW';`  -- Is this what you are asking for?  That should return `2`.

Comment: `SELECT data_id FROM TBL WHERE status = 'REVIEW' limit 1 ` this query give me an id.